# Redirect to root from directories

Tags: .htaccess

In the following example I'm trying to redirect the directories `login` and `blog` with their respecting subdirectories back to the site root.

```
example.com
    login
        address
        profile

    blog
        page1
        page2
        page3

    contact
        login
            address
            profile
```

Best attempt so far:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(login|blog)(.*) /
```

The problem here is that pages like `example.com/contact/login/address` will redirect to `example.com/contact/` which makes absolutely sense, but how can I avoid this? Or rather is ther something like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 {SITE_ROOT}/(login|blog)(.*) /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use start anchor `^` in your regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(login|blog)(/.*)?$ /
```